# Query gives same result multiple times

Tags: php, sql

I'm using this code to show similar entry's to the one that's currently showing.

```
 $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM planten WHERE cat = '$cat' ORDER BY rand() limit 3")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

  $naam_gerelateerd = $row['naam'];
  $mintemp = $row['mintemp'];    

     echo $naam_gerelateerd;

 }
```

Now I get 3 times the same echo.

(Lets say my current page is "Product 1", this box should show 3 similar products. But currently it echo's 3x "Product 1")

Also, how can I make my code sql-injection-protected? I've read something about PDO, but how safe is this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result set is fetching array into `$row2` in a loop, but you're setting the value of `$naam_gerelateerd` from `$row`, which is apparently defined outside the loop.

Comment: Ugh.. How dumb of me! Thank you for pointing that out!
I should take a break now ;-)